# Angular, How to trigger one of multiple animations

Tags: angular

I have two list of items, and I want to animate each of them when the `fa caret which belongs to it parent` is clicked.

here is `html`:

```
<li>
  <div>
    <span> something1</span>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" (click)="toggleList()"></i>
  </div>
 <ul [@elementState]="showlist">
   <li>something2</li>
   <li>something3</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <div>
    <span>something4</span>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" (click)="toggleList()"></i>
  </div>
  <ul  [@elementState]="showlist">
      <li >something5</li>
      <li >something6</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

here is `ts` from @component:

```
   animations: [
    trigger('elementState', [
      state('show', style({
        'height':'88px'
      })),
      state('hide',   style({
        'hide':'0px'
      })),
      transition('show <=> hide', animate('300ms'))
    ])
  ]
```

and here is some `ts` from class:

```
showlist = 'hide';


  toggleList(){
       this.showlist = this.showlist === 'hide' ? 'show' : 'hide';
  }
```

And I am aiming to make those two list open separetly, because for the moment each icon click triggers animation for both list and that is not what I would like to happen.

I thought of making individual animation for each but there would be a lot code repetition so if thats possible I want to avoid that.

Does anyone know the trick to make it work ?

Comment: Problem is that both are bound to the same property of the containing component: `showlist`. The behavior you are seeing is to be expected.

Comment: I am aware of that, just need a simple way to get around and make animation works each of them separetly .

Comment: Then use 2 separate properties

Comment: Go with answer I will approve it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable for both of the unordered lists, obviously they will trigger at the same time.

Instead of using a string variable 'show' and 'hide' to trigger your animations, you can use a boolean and check if the unordered list is the one you want to animate. You can use your imagination to think of whatever you want to use but i'll give you a simple example:

```
animations: [
    trigger('elementState', [
      state('1', style({
        'height':'88px'
      })),
      state('0',   style({
        'hide':'0px'
      })),
      transition('0 <=> 1', animate('300ms'))
    ])
  ]

<ul [@elementState]="showlist == 'list1'"> // or 'list2'

(click)="showlist = 'list1'" // or 'list2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you will use `*ngFor` here, 
accordingly writing answer

```
<li *ngFor = "let something of something_list; let showlist = false">
  <div>
    <span> something1</span>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" (click)="showlist = !showlist"></i>
  </div>
  <ul [@elementState]="showlist ? 'show' : 'hide'>
    <li>something2</li>
    <li>something3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Here I have declared local variable for each list item using let ***(see `let showlist = false`)*** by default its `false`

on click toggling that to `true/false` ***(see `(click)="showlist = !showlist"`)***

and finally if `showlist` is true will trigger state "show" else "hide" these are states which you have defined within your animation ***(see `[@elementState]="showlist ? 'show' : 'hide'`)***